# Custom Choices Labels and Display in Django 1.3.1

Tags: django

I know the Django Dev version is going to make this easy with [this addition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect), but is there any way to customize the choice fields for radio buttons in the current version of django?  The commented version is what I'm looking to do. The problem is, when the form is invalid, the form reloads without any of the original entries entered.

```
<div class="category box">
    <p class="question">Category:</p>
    {{ form.category.errors }}
    {{ form.category }}
    {% comment %}
    <ul>
    <li><label for="id_category_0"><input type="radio" id="id_category_0" value="E" name="category"><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/icons/eating.png"><br />Eating</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_category_1"><input type="radio" id="id_category_1" value="D" name="category"><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/icons/drinking.png"><br />Drinking</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_category_2"><input type="radio" id="id_category_2" value="S" name="category"><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/icons/sleeping.png"><br />Sleeping</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_category_3"><input type="radio" id="id_category_3" value="P" name="category"><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/icons/exploring.png"><br />Exploring</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_category_4"><input type="radio" id="id_category_4" value="O" name="category"><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/icons/other.png"><br />Other</label></li>
    </ul>
    {% endcomment %}
</div>
<div class="rating box">
    <p class="question">How would you rate it??</p>
    {{ form.rating.errors }}
    {{ form.rating }}
    {% comment %}
    <ul>
        <li><label for="id_rating_0"><input type="radio" id="id_rating_0" value="1" name="rating"><span class="glyph" style="color: lightgreen;">j</span> Must Do</label></li>
        <li><label for="id_rating_1"><input type="radio" id="id_rating_1" value="2" name="rating"><span class="glyph" style="color: lightblue;">l</span> Do</label></li>
        <li><label for="id_rating_2"><input type="radio" id="id_rating_2" value="3" name="rating"><span class="glyph">L</span> Miss</label></li>
    </ul>
    {% endcomment %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're bypassing the rendering logic of the widget, which means it doesn't know how to display the currently selected value.

You could do something hacky and inspect the form's data in the template itself. But a nicer way is to subclass `forms.widgets.RadioFieldRenderer` and write your own render function. I've done it in this example to render each radio input in it's own `<td>`, I was making a multiple choice quiz where all the questions had the same answer format.

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
from django.utils.html import conditional_escape

class ReportRadioInput(forms.widgets.RadioInput):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return mark_safe(u'%s' % self.tag())


class ReportRadioRenderer(forms.widgets.RadioFieldRenderer):
    def __iter__(self):
        for i, choice in enumerate(self.choices):
            yield ReportRadioInput(self.name, self.value, self.attrs.copy(), choice, i)    

    def render(self):
        """Outputs a <ul> for this set of radio fields."""
        return mark_safe(u'\n'.join([u'<td class="choice">%s</td>'
                % force_unicode(w) for w in self]))


class AnswerForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        questionnaire = kwargs.pop('questionnaire')
        super(AnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)    

        self.fieldsets = []

        for g in questionnaire.groups.all():
            fields = []

            for q in g.questions.all():
                fieldname = 'question_%i' % q.pk
                widget = forms.RadioSelect(renderer=ReportRadioRenderer)
                self.fields[fieldname] = forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=int, empty_value=None, required=True, label=q.text, choices=CHOICES, widget=widget)
                fields.append(self[fieldname])
            self.fieldsets.append(dict(legend=g.name,fields=fields))
```

The bit that will interest you is the `ReportRadioRenderer`, and the use of `widget = forms.RadioSelect(renderer=ReportRadioRenderer)`